# Change HTML Code with BeautifulSoup and "reload" like developer tools in Chrome

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Lets assume I have an html site with an embedded Video from a video hoster of your choice.

The code looks like so (YouTube):

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Some_Video" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I go into the Chrome Developer tools I can inspect the HTML-Code and change something and immediately see the results. Now I want to change the YouTube-Video Link into some other Video Link like:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Some_Other_Video" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And want to check whats happened. For example check the title or something else. How can I do this automated with python and BeautifulSoup? It's critical for me to do this on the website not direct accessing the link with my browser.

**Edit:** Let me clarify my question. This is what I want to archieve step by step:
1. I want to get the html-code inside the iframe
2. I want to change the "src"-attribute of the iframe to something different
3. The edited html-code must be refreshed 
4. I want to extract the new html-code inside the iframe

Comment: Is it critical you do that on your website?
What's the point in not directly getting infos from youtube? anyway your iframe does nothing else than redirecting you to youtube...

Comment: YouTube was only a simple example. It's critical because there is a check present If you accessing the content over the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the browser with Selenium from remote. Make your changes and send chrome console files through e-mail or somehow. Here is the some informative tutorial below;

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/

Find the "Controlling the Browser with the selenium Module"

Comment: Can't find an option to change the HMTL code and recheck for certain changes?

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
html = '''<iframe width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Some_Video" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.iframe['src']="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Some_Other_Video"
```

out:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Some_Video" width="640"></iframe>
```

You can change the attribute of tag by access it like dict, but I have no idea why you want to get the HTML code inside the iframe.
This is what I can do.

Comment: I want the Code inside the iframe because there I can find the link to the file over a CDN.